# Canvas draw rectangle only when keyboard is pressed

Tags: javascript, canvas, keycode

I am drawing rectangles on a canvas using mouse.  However, I want to activate the mouse action to draw the rectangles only when key `d` is pressed on the key board.

If I use

```
if (event.ctrlKey) {
 //draw rectangles
}
```

I am able to draw by holding the ctrlKey on the keyboard.
However, if I use

```
if (e.which == 88) {
 //draw rectangles
}
```

it doesn't work.  I am not able to bind the keyboard keypress events to mouse events on a canvas.  I understand canvas element does not have onKeyPress event and as suggested in some of the blogs, I tried the following code, which doesn't work.  How can I get started?

I have many events for which I have to bind the keyboard press event on the canvas.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>parallelogram</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:solid 1px;margin:0;padding:0;;z-index:1"></canvas>
</body>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas, context;
var dragging = false;
var startLocation;
var dragStartLocation;
var dragStopLocation;
var dragThirdLocation;
var snapshot;
var coords = [];
var pointsNum = 0;
var d = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};

//Get mouse click coordinates
function getCanvasCoordinates(event)
{
    var x = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var y = event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    };
}

//save the canvas original state
function takeSnapShot()
{
    snapshot = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

//restore the canvas original state
function restoreSnapShot()
{
    context.putImageData(snapshot, 0, 0);
}

//draw a point on mouse click
function drawPoint(position)
{
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(position.x, position.y, 5.5, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.stroke();
}

//draw a line on mouse move
function drawLine(start, end)
{
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
    context.lineTo(end.x, end.y);
    context.stroke();
}

//start the event with first mouse click
function dragStart(event)
{
    dragging = true;
    dragStartLocation = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
    coords['imageClicked'] = localStorage.getItem('clickedImage');
    console.log(coords);
    var brandNode = localStorage.getItem('brandNode');
    var locationNode = localStorage.getItem('locationNode');
    drawPoint(dragStartLocation);
    pointsNum++;
    takeSnapShot();
    if (pointsNum == 1) startLocation = dragStartLocation;
}

//draw a line along with the mouse move from the first click
function drag(event)
{
    var position;
    if (snapshot && pointsNum && pointsNum < 3)
    {
        restoreSnapShot();
        position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
        drawLine(dragStartLocation, position);
        drawPoint(position);
        if (pointsNum == 2) drawFourthCoord(position)

    }
}

//stop the mouse movement and drawing line.
function dragStop(event)
{
    dragging = false;
    restoreSnapShot();
    var position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
    dragStopLocation = position;
    drawPoint(dragStopLocation);
    pointsNum++;
    drawLine(dragStartLocation, dragStopLocation);
    takeSnapShot();
    d = {
        x: dragStartLocation.x - dragStopLocation.x,
        y: dragStartLocation.y - dragStopLocation.y
    };

    dragStartLocation = position;
    console.log(dragStartLocation);
    if (pointsNum > 3) pointsNum = 0;
}

//draw the fourth coordinate
function drawFourthCoord(position)
{
    var p = {
        x: position.x + d.x,
        y: position.y + d.y
    };
    drawLine(position, p);
    drawPoint(p);
    drawLine(startLocation, p);
}

/*
  This code works...but does not have binding to keyCode x
  function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.lineCap = "round";
  context.lineWidth = 3;
  context.strokeStyle = '#f4d03f';
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', dragStop, false);  

}

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
*/

var canvaskey = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvaskey.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);

function doKeyDown(e)
{
    if (e.which == 88)
    {
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.lineCap = "round";
        context.lineWidth = 3;
        context.strokeStyle = '#f4d03f';
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', dragStop, false);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply hold a *semaphor* variable in the scope your drawing functions have access to.

On keydown of required key, set it to `true`, on keyup to `false`.
In the draw function, check the semaphor is set to `true`, otherwise, return promptly.

```js
// our keydown semaphor
var d_down = false;

function doKeyDown(e)
{
    if (e.key == "d")
    {
      d_down = true;
    }
}
function doKeyUp(e)
{
    if (e.key == "d")
    {
      d_down = false;
    }
}


var canvas, context;
var dragging = false;
var startLocation;
var dragStartLocation;
var dragStopLocation;
var dragThirdLocation;
var snapshot;
var coords = [];
var pointsNum = 0;
var d = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};

//Get mouse click coordinates
function getCanvasCoordinates(event)
{
    var x = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var y = event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    };
}

//save the canvas original state
function takeSnapShot()
{
    snapshot = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

//restore the canvas original state
function restoreSnapShot()
{
    context.putImageData(snapshot, 0, 0);
}

//draw a point on mouse click
function drawPoint(position)
{
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(position.x, position.y, 5.5, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.stroke();
}

//draw a line on mouse move
function drawLine(start, end)
{
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
    context.lineTo(end.x, end.y);
    context.stroke();
}

//start the event with first mouse click
function dragStart(event)
{
  // check our semaphor
  if(!d_down)
    return; // we're not allowed to go farther
    
    dragging = true;
    dragStartLocation = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
/*    coords['imageClicked'] = localStorage.getItem('clickedImage');
    console.log(coords);
    var brandNode = localStorage.getItem('brandNode');
    var locationNode = localStorage.getItem('locationNode');*/
    drawPoint(dragStartLocation);
    pointsNum++;
    takeSnapShot();
    if (pointsNum == 1) startLocation = dragStartLocation;
}

//draw a line along with the mouse move from the first click
function drag(event)
{
  // check our semaphor
  if(!d_down)
    return; // we're not allowed to go farther
    var position;
    if (snapshot && pointsNum && pointsNum < 3)
    {
        restoreSnapShot();
        position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
        drawLine(dragStartLocation, position);
        drawPoint(position);
        if (pointsNum == 2) drawFourthCoord(position)

    }
}

//stop the mouse movement and drawing line.
function dragStop(event)
{
    dragging = false;
  // check our semaphor
  if(!d_down)
    return; // we're not allowed to go farther
    restoreSnapShot();
    var position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
    dragStopLocation = position;
    drawPoint(dragStopLocation);
    pointsNum++;
    drawLine(dragStartLocation, dragStopLocation);
    takeSnapShot();
    d = {
        x: dragStartLocation.x - dragStopLocation.x,
        y: dragStartLocation.y - dragStopLocation.y
    };

    dragStartLocation = position;
//    console.log(dragStartLocation);
    if (pointsNum > 3) pointsNum = 0;
}

//draw the fourth coordinate
function drawFourthCoord(position)
{
    var p = {
        x: position.x + d.x,
        y: position.y + d.y
    };
    drawLine(position, p);
    drawPoint(p);
    drawLine(startLocation, p);
}

  function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.lineCap = "round";
  context.lineWidth = 3;
  context.strokeStyle = '#f4d03f';
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', dragStop, false); 
  snapshot = context.createImageData(1,1)

}

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

var canvaskey = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvaskey.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown);
canvaskey.addEventListener('keyup', doKeyUp);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:solid 1px;margin:0;padding:0;;z-index:1" tabindex="1"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you.  The code works on SO Run Code Snippet option, however, strangely when I replicate the same on my machine, I could not draw.  Exactly the same code, without any additions or deletions.

Comment: thank  you again...that's what I tried indeed (copied the script content) but still not working....not sure if I have missed something....I have copied the changed code temporarily at the bottom of my query...if you want to extend your help....thanks in advance..

Comment: @Apricot [here it is as a single html file](http://plnkr.co/edit/vnfNQ3PxuwD4VzPTbmpy?p=preview). you may have missed the `tabindex` attribute on the canvas element, required to listen for key events on the canvas element (if you wish, you could listen for it at the document level, and get rid of this attribute).

Comment: Many thanks for all the help.  Indeed i missed the tabindex.  When I corrected it I could draw the rectangles.  It works on Firefox...not on chrome.  But that's something I will figure out.  Many many thanks again.

Comment: @Apricot oh right, Chrome requires a value for the tabindex attribtue to work... updated